# Why webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders doesn't provide query string while browser.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate does?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to implement a web extension which removes redirect intermediate from links. For example, when you click any link to foreign site from vk.com (a social network), you'll be navigated to `https://vk.com/away.php?to=URL_GOES_HERE`.

When you listen to `onBeforeNavigate` events like that:

```
browser.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(
    (details) => {
        console.log('before navigate', details);
    }, {
        url: [
            {hostContains: "vk.com"}
        ]
    }
);
```

you'll get full URL: `before navigate Object { url: "https://vk.com/away.php?to=URL_GOES_HERE", timeStamp: 1488807415002, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 2 }`

But you have no option to replace that navigation action with another URL. You have that ability only for `webRequest` API:

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    (details) => {
        console.log('before web request', details)
    },
    {urls: [
        '*://vk.com/away.php'
    ]},
    ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']
);
```

but URL there doesn't contain query parameters: `before web request Object { requestId: "1", url: "http://vk.com/away.php", originUrl: "https://vk.com/feed", method: "GET", type: "main_frame", timeStamp: 1488807415092, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 2, requestHeaders: Array[6] }`

Why is it working so? Is it a bug or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns) doesn't clealy states that query string is implicitly treated as part of URL path. So asterisk at the end is required. The following code works and removes intermediate request:

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    (details) => {
        let url = new URL(details.url), param;
        switch (url.hostname) {
            case 'vk.com':
                param = 'to';
                break;
            default:
                param = 'url';
        }
        let direct = new URLSearchParams(url.search).get(param);
        console.log('DIRECT: ' + direct + ' (' + url + ')');
        return {redirectUrl: direct}
    },
    {urls: [
        '*://vk.com/away.php?*',
        '*://www.google.ru/url?*',
        '*://www.google.com/url?*',
    ]},
    ['blocking']
);
```